# Find the coordinates of the vector $ v = (2,4) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $ with respect to certain bases of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the coordinates of the vector $ v = (2,4) $ in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ with respect to the following bases $ B $ of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $.

For $ B = \{ (0,-4),(1,0) \} $:
$$
  V_{B}
= 2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -4 \end{bmatrix} + 4 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
= (4,-8).
$$

For $ B = \{ (1,1),(2,3) \} $:
$$
  V_{B}
= 2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + 4 \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
= (10,14).
$$

Are these correct? I seem to be finding linear combinations, which makes me suspicious as to whether I did things correctly or not.

Comment: I wonder if the question is to *find* $a$ and $b$ s.t. $a [0, -4]+b[1,0]=[2,4]$ and accordingly for the latter. Anyway, you are right, you are writing a linear combination, but it's not a problem.

Comment: So are you essentially saying that the coordinate vector with respect to the basis in this case is equivalent to the linear combination?

Comment: You pass from coordinates to vector, by a linear combination of the basis vectors (the coefficients being the coordinates).

Comment: So they are not the same, when computing the way you suggested i get (-1,2) and (1-b, 4/3 - a)

Comment: Even more confused now then when i started haha

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549694/how-to-find-the-coordinate-vector) and its answer look very relevant.

Comment: checking it out now

Comment: Yes, it was very similar and it helped me but this one is different in the sense that it actually has a basis coordinate involved so i solved it, i believe it could potentially benefit others. Thank you though for point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could someone please verify real quick and mark the answer as correct. THank you

Answer (score 0):

This was similar to a previous post but it does differ in some respects, what i wrote above is in fact a linear combination and not what the problem is asking.

This is the proper way to solve: 
 $$\mathcal{B_1}=\left\{\vec{v}_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{r}0\\-4\end{array}\right],\vec{v}_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{r}1\\0\end{array}\right]\right\}\implies$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\-4&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{r}x\\y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{r}0x+y\\-4x+0y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{r}2\\4\end{array}\right]\implies V_B=(-1,2)$$
For $B_2$ we have:

$$\mathcal{B_2}=\left\{\vec{v}_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{r}1\\1\end{array}\right],\vec{v}_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{r}2\\3\end{array}\right]\right\}\implies$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&2\\1&3\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{r}x\\y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{r}x+2y\\x+3y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{r}2\\4\end{array}\right]\implies V_B=(-2,2)$$

Note: to solve the second system you must:

$$z_1 = x + 3y , z_2 = x + 2y$$
$z_1 - z_2$ to get y value.